# Android work manager PeriodicWorkRequest not working

Tags: android, android-workmanager

I want to set a periodic task to be performed after every x hours (not exactly x hours but a minimum of x hrs). This needs be done even after my application's main activity is destroyed or after device re-boots. So as per android developer docs, I have selected work manager class for the same. But the code is not working after first execution. My code is:-

(I am using enqueueUniquePeriodicWork to avoid multiple requests)

In main activity oncreate:-

```
    Constraints constraints = new Constraints.Builder()
            .setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.CONNECTED)
            .build();


    PeriodicWorkRequest uploadWorkRequest = new PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(UploadWorker.class,16, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
            .setBackoffCriteria(
                    BackoffPolicy.LINEAR,
                    OneTimeWorkRequest.MIN_BACKOFF_MILLIS,
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .addTag("workerTest")
            .setConstraints(constraints)
            .build();

    WorkManager.getInstance().enqueueUniquePeriodicWork("mytag", ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.REPLACE, uploadWorkRequest);
```

In Upload

```
public class UploadWorker extends Worker {

public UploadWorker(
        @NonNull Context context,
        @NonNull WorkerParameters params) {
    super(context, params);

}

@NonNull
@Override
public Result doWork() {

    appendLog(Calendar. getInstance().getTime().toString() + "work manager periodic ");
    Log.d("TAG","work manager dowork callback");
    return Result.success(outputData);
}





public static void appendLog(String text) {
    String fileName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + "mylogs.txt";

    File logFile = new File(fileName);
    if (!logFile.exists())
    {
        try
        {
            logFile.createNewFile();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            Log.d("TAG","Error:- "+e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    try
    {
        //BufferedWriter for performance, true to set append to file flag
        BufferedWriter buf = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(logFile, true));
        buf.append(text);
        buf.newLine();
        buf.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        Log.d("TAG","Errors:- "+e.toString());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

What is wrong with my code? Why is it running one time only and not further?

Comment: Is this device-specific?  Do you experience the same problem on a stock emulator?

Comment: What happen if you try without writing to file ?